# Reference conversion between class and its interface

Tags: c#

I have a class that implement an interface:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    string MY_VALUE { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass: IMyInterface
{
    public string MY_VALUE { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the class in a list:

```
private List<MyClass> MyInternal;
public List<IMyInterface> MyExternal
{
    get
    {
        return MyInternal;
    }
}
```

The problem here is that MyInternal is of type MyClass so the get function have error.

However, if I cast MyInternal to IMyInterface first, it would get rid of the error but would stop being useful because it's a new list and not the original list:

```
public List<IMyInterface> MyExternal
{
    get
    {
        return MyInternal.Select(x=>(IMyInterface)x).ToList();
    }
}
```

I am calling the external property like this:

```
MyService.MyExternal.Add(new MyClass{ MY_VALUE:"New Value" });
```

This would fail since MyExternal is not mapped to MyInternal but a new list.  How do I make this work?

Comment: Do you *actually* want the list to have any object implementing the interface in it, or do you want it to only have `MyClass` instances?  You can't have both; so just choose one.

Comment: `List` is not covariant.  If you define `MyExternal` as `IEnumerble<IMyInterface>` then you can return `List<MyClass>` from it as `IEnumerable` doesn't allow you to pass in a `IMyInterface` that might not be a `MyClass`.  But it sounds like you just want to expose `List<MyClass>` if you plan to add to it.

Comment: But then I wouldn't be able to add to IEnumerable

Comment: @YongkeBillYu Indeed, because the ability to add to it is what makes it not work.

Comment: That kind of defeat the purpose of my service

Comment: @YongkeBillYu why not just make `MyInternal` a `List<IMyInterface>`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast `List<MyClass>` as a `List<MyInterface>` even though `MyClass` implements `MyInterface`.

If you could cast it as a `List<MyInterface>`, you would have to be able to add anything to it that implements `MyInterface`, even if it wasn't a `MyClass`. If you could cast it as a `List<MyInterface>`, pass that reference to another method, that method would "think" that it could add something else to that list, when really the only thing that can go in that list is `MyClass`. We never run into those scenarios because the compiler prevents it.

If you have a `List<MyClass>` and want a `List<MyInterface>` you could do

```
var listOfMyInterface = listOfMyClass.Cast<MyInterface>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine I did a

```
public class MyClass2: IMyInterface
{
    public string MY_VALUE { get; set; }
}
```

then I did

```
someClass.MyExternal.Add(new MyClass2())
```

It would have to add a `MyClass2` to the `private List<MyClass> MyInternal` object which is not allowed. That is why you can't do it.

To get around it you must expose a interface that is co-variant (only allows reading of the list, no writing, and has `out T` as the type), this is what the [`IReadOnlyList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385(v=vs.110).aspx) interface is for, and `List<T>` implements that interface.

```
private List<MyClass> MyInternal;
public IReadOnlyList<IMyInterface> MyExternal
{
    get
    {
        return MyInternal;
    }
}
```

Other possible good candidates for interfaces to choose from that also could work are [`IReadOnlyCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh881542(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

If you want the list exposed by `MyExternal` to remain writable your only option is change MyInternal to use the same type of list.

```
private List<IMyInterface> MyInternal;
public List<IMyInterface> MyExternal
{
    get
    {
        return MyInternal;
    }
}
```